# NameError: undefined local variable or method `params' for main:Object from (irb):7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

this is the subjects_controller

```
class SubjectsController < ApplicationController
 layout false
 def index
 @subjects = Subject.order("position ASC")
 end

 def show

 @subject = Subject.find(params[:id])

 end

 def new
 end

 def edit
 end

 def delet
 end
end
```

and this is the 'show.html.erb'

```
<%= link_to("<< Back to List", {:class => 'index'})  :class => 'back-   link)'%>
<div class ="subjects show">
<h2>Show Subject</h2>

<table sammary="Subject detail view">
 <tr>
     <th>Name</th>

     <td><%=  @subject.name  %></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <th>Position</th>
    <td><%= @subject.position %> </th>
 </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Visible</th>
    <td><%= @subject.visible ? 'true': 'flse' %> </th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <th>Created</th>
    <td><%= @subject.created_at %> </th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <th>Updated</th>
    <td><%= @subject.updated_at %> </th>
 </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

so when i click on something  on the browser i don't get anything and when i did this on rails console

```
Subject.find(params[:id])
```

i  get this message  
NameError: undefined local variable or method `params' for main:Object from (irb):7

Comment: because irb/console doesn't know what params is.

Answer (score 0):

`params` is undefined in your current console context.  You're trying to recreate controller code in your console.  In the controller, `params` is automatically assigned according to the incoming HTTP request parameters.  In the console params is undefined unless you explicitly assign it.  Try this in your console:

```
params = {id: 1}
Subject.find(params[:id])
```

It will not throw an error if `Subject` is in fact an ActiveRecord model.

What are you really trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to debug your controller, use [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) or [byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug) to get a debug console for the specific context for example:

```
def edit
  binding.pry
  @subject = Subject.find(params[:id])
end
```

Go to the `subjects/1/edit` path, rails server stops at the break point and you can access the debug console.